# Frequency Table, binary variable,condition in r

Tags: r, frequency

I am currently working on the following data frame:

```
     ID         Person        Rain             car.1   cars.2  car.3  car.4
1    31         1             no rain            1      0       1      0
2    31         1             no rain            0      1       0      0
3    31         1             rain               1      1       0      1
4    31         1             rain               0      0       0      0
5    31         1             rain               0      1       0      1
6    32         2             no rain            0      0       0      0
7    32         2             no rain            1      1       1      1
8    32         2             rain               0      0       0      0
9    32         2             no rain            1      1       0      1
10   32         2             rain               0      0       0      0
11   33         3             no rain            1      1       1      1
```

The data frame has the following meaning:
Each Person has 5 rows, in which the person says which car it used, for example Person 1 used car 1 and car 3.
What I want to do is, get something like a frequency table where based on the condition if it rained or not and the combinations of cars used .
In total we can get the following combinations of cars:

(car1), (car2), (car3), (car4), (car1, car2), (car1, car3), (car1, car4), (car2, car3), (car2, car4), (car3, car4),

(car1, car2, car3),......(car1, car2, car3, car4)

I want something like that:

```
                         rain    no rain
car1                       1         4
car2                       1         3
car3                       0         3
car4                       2         3
car1, car2                 1         3
.....
car1, car2, car3, car4     0         1
```

When it rained car1 was used once and with no rain car1 was used 4 times.

I tried something like:

```
xtabs( ~Rain + car.1 + car.2 + car.3 + car.4 ,data = df)
```

but I have trouble to interpret the results

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` library -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cols <- grep('car', names(df), value = TRUE)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = toString(cols[c_across(starts_with('car')) == 1])) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(result != '') %>%
  count(result, Rain) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Rain, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

The logic is to create one comma-separated string for each row in `result`. If a column has value as 1 we include that column name in `result`. Drop the rows that has all 0's and `count` occurrence for every combination.

Comment: Thank you a lot, unfortunately this doesn't work, as I am getting the following result: # A tibble: 0 x 2
# … with 2 variables: result <chr>, n <int>

Comment: Maybe one of your variable is called something else. It would be easier to help if you provide data in reproducible format. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).